# Change UITextField size programmatically

Tags: uitextfield, xcode4.5, cgrectmake

I have a UITextField in my storyboard, which I bind to the ViewController.h with

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
```

In the ViewController.m I want to change the size and position of this UITextField username

```
[_username setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 200.0)];
```

I get no error, but nothing is happening to the UITextField username. It's still the same like in the IB.

What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: why is the textfield defined as `username` but used as `_username`?

Comment: that's new in xcode 4.5 instead of synthesize